# React native I put a splash screen in app.js and I get an error

Tags: react-native

This error code appeared on the connected iPhone. I need help.

I will write additional app.js code as needed.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

According to the error message, .length is being called on an undefined object. Take a look at AppIntroSlider, see if the issue is with this component.